# Падает телеграм бот для управления VPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, vps, expect

У меня имеется бот в телеграм, я его поставил на хост и мне захотелось создать второго бота через которого я мог бы управлять первым ботом (Перезапуск, включение).

Знакомый дал мне такого бота я прописал туда данные vps сервера от основного бота, запустил его, проблема заключается в том, что когда я отдаю команду о запуске своего основного бота или о рестарте у меня выдают ниженаписанную ошибку, но если допустим я просто отдам команду пингануть сервер, то бот мне спокойно отправляет данные с о работоспособности и пинге сервера с основным ботом.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 185, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 439, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 136, in handle_message_received
    ssh.expect('[Pp]assword')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 344, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 181, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7f1e1278fb00>
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'qqqq@qqq1.qqqqqq.qqqq.vps.qqqqqq.ru']
buffer (last 100 chars): b'k02FYg9OYShfrI722jOgsLgrM0mPAFuMNIL88IxCSA.\r\nAre you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? '
before (last 100 chars): b'k02FYg9OYShfrI722jOgsLgrM0mPAFuMNIL88IxCSA.\r\nAre you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? '
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 1581
child_fd: 11
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'[Pp]assword')
```

Comment: не проще ватчдог на первом сервере поставить для бота ? Ну и код второго неплохо было бы увидеть

Comment: @Evgeniy, привет слушай, не подскажешь что такое? Просто не слыхал.

Comment: Проще загуглить. Так и пишешь в поиске "линукс ватчдог"